# Play Framework Java - Form validation error

Tags: java, forms, validation, data-binding, playframework

I'm trying to fill my User Form in Java Play! 2.4.3, but i always get a "IllegalStateException: No value"

This is the code from the Controller:

```
Form<User> uf = Form.form(User.class);

uf.fill( new User( "felix@abc.com" , "123") );

if (uf.hasErrors()){
    return ok("Form Error");
}

// IllegalStateException: No value
uf.get();
```

User.class:

```
@Constraints.Required
private String email;
@Constraints.Required
private String password;

public User(){}

public User(String email, String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

//Getter
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

//Setter
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

I also tried to fill the Form with the bind Method and a HashMap but get the same Error

```
Form<User> uf = Form.form(User.class);    

Map<String,String> data = new HashMap();
data.put("email", "felix@abc.com");
data.put("password", "123");

User user = uf.bind(data);

if (uf.hasErrors()){
    return ok("Form Error");
}

// IllegalStateException: No value
uf.get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.fill` method returns a new `Form` object ([see here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/702e89841fc54f5603a0d981c3488ed9883561fe/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L499)). So I belive this should work (didnt test):

```
Form<User> uf = Form.form(User.class);

Form<User> newUf = uf.fill( new User( "felix@abc.com" , "123") );

if (newUf.hasErrors()){
    return ok("Form Error");
}

// Should Work
newu=Uf.get();
```

And it seems the story is also the same for `.bind` ([as seen here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/702e89841fc54f5603a0d981c3488ed9883561fe/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L419-L450)).